# Group by in a nested dictionary by a particular nested dictionary key in c#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, grouping

I am trying to group a nested dictionary based on a value for one of the dictionary keys.

```
Dictionary<Dictionary<string, object>, string> data= new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, object>, string>();
```

The dictionary looks something like:

```
{
  {[value, 166], [entryDate, 1/1/2016], [id, 1]}, "vitalweight"},
  {[value, 176], [entryDate, 6/2/2016], [id, 2]}, "vitalweight"},
  {[value, 126], [entryDate, 1/1/2016], [id, 1]}, "vitalpulse"},
  {[value, 100], [entryDate, 1/1/2016], [id, 1]}, "vitaltemp"},
  {[value, 98], [entryDate, 6/2/2016], [id, 2]}, "vitaltemp"}
}
```

I am trying to group this data by `entryDate` which happens to be one of the key in a nested dictionary so that I can have grouped list like:

```
{
  {[value, 166], [entryDate, 1/1/2016], [id, 1]}, "vitalweight"},
  {[value, 126], [entryDate, 1/1/2016], [id, 1]}, "vitalpulse"},
  {[value, 100], [entryDate, 1/1/2016], [id, 1]}, "vitaltemp"}
},
{
  {[value, 176], [entryDate, 6/2/2016], [id, 2]}, "vitalweight"},
  {[value, 98], [entryDate, 6/2/2016], [id, 2]}, "vitaltemp"}
}
```

I have tried different ways, none I was able to complete so, I have nothing to show. But was trying to use linq query to group it. I would appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Not sure what is the desired output, but if the inner dictionaries always contains a key "entryDate", then `data.GroupBy(item => item.Key["entryDate"])` should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = new Dictionary<Dictionary<string, object>, string>()
{
    {new Dictionary<string, object> {{"value", 166},{"entryDate", "1/1/2016"},{"id", "1"},},"vitalweight"},
    {new Dictionary<string, object> {{"value", 176},{"entryDate", "6/2/2016"},{"id", "2"},},"vitalweight"},
    {new Dictionary<string, object> {{"value", 126},{"entryDate", "1/1/2016"},{"id", "1"},},"vitalpulse"},
    {new Dictionary<string, object> {{"value", 100},{"entryDate", "1/1/2016"},{"id", "1"},},"vitaltemp"},
    {new Dictionary<string, object> {{"value", 98},{"entryDate", "6/2/2016"},{"id", "2"},},"vitaltemp"},
};

data.GroupBy(d=>d.Key["entryDate"]);
```

This assumes, that **all** of your key dictionaries do have this key.

And i have output:

[image]